# Space with semi-locally simply connected open subsets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A topological space $X$ is semi-locally simply connected if, for any $x\in X$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that any loop in $U$ is homotopically equivalent to a constant one in $X$ or, equivalently, if the functor $$\Pi_1(U)\rightarrow\Pi_1(X)$$ induced by the inclusion $U\subseteq X$ factorizes through a groupoid in which for each pair of objects there is at most one morphism.

My question is: is it true that if a locally path connected space $X$ is such that, for any open subset $U\subseteq X$, $U$ is semi-locally simply connected, then $X$ must be *locally simply connected*?

Comment: Sorry, I've misread.

Comment: Your equivalent reformulation of "any loop in $U$ is homotopic to a constant one in $X$" is only valid if $U$ is pathconnected : you should say that the image of this functor has at most one arrow between any two points

Comment: You're right, in my mind I was assuming without a reason that $X$ is locally path connected. Thank you, I will make an edit.

Comment: Even if $X$ is locally path-connected (which is an assumption we might be tempted to make) that's not the same thing !

Comment: Why not? If $X$ is locally path connected, we might assume that $U$ is path connected, so $\Pi_1(U)$ is equivalent to the $\pi_1(U)$. In this situation, $\pi_1(U, x)\rightarrow\pi_1(X, x)$ is trivial if and only if $\Pi_1(U)\simeq\pi_1(U,x)\rightarrow\Pi_1(X)$ is trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry for my previous answer, I misread the question. But now I need some clarification on the question. Your hypothesis is that any open $U$ is semi local simply connected, right? In particular are you asking that any $U$ is connected or that any connected open set $U$ is semi local simply connected? (Because a space where any open is connected for istance is non hausdorff and I assume you want hausdorff spaces)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by having "locally" a property P? that every $x$ has a neighborhood having P or that any $x$ has a local basis of open sets having P? For instance if every open set is semi local simply connected then the whole space is simply connected because any loop is contained in an open set. So any point has a neighborhood which is simply connected: the whole space. The things are different if "locally" means  "there is a local basis..."

Comment: @user126154 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_simply_connected_space (Usually "locally $P$" is that that there is a basis whose elements as subspaces are $P$.)  It is not true that semilocally simply connected implies simply connected, since simply connected requires path connected as well.  As I note in my partial answer, we ought to include locally path connected to the list of hypotheses (and I see the question has been recently modified to add this condition).

Comment: @kyle Miller I don't say that semi loc simply conn. Implies simply conn. I say that "every open set is semi loc simply conn." Implies simply connected.

Comment: @user126154 The two-point discrete topology is not simply connected (since it's not path connected), yet still every open subset is semilocally simply connected.

Comment: Ok, if you include that a simply connected space is path connected, but the core of the fact is that: any open set is semi local simpluy connected implies that any loop in X is trivial, so any path-connected component of X is simply connected according to wikipedia definition.

Comment: @KyleMiller as for the use of "local" it depents, it is a choice. For isntance, locally compact space are usually spaces such that any point has a compact neighborhood, it is not required to have a local basis. (wikipedia also agree on this).

Comment: @user126154 Every open set of a manifold is semilocally simply connected (since manifolds are locally simply connected), but many manifolds aren't simply connected.

Comment: @KyleMiller this time you convinced me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is the union of line segments from $(0,0)$ to $(x,1)$, where $x\in\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z},n>0\}$.  This is simply connected and "locally semilocally simply connected", but it is not locally simply connected because it is not locally path connected. (The definition of simply connected is that $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ are trivial.)

Perhaps the hypotheses imply that the space is locally $\pi_1$-trivial -- I could not think of an example that wasn't.

Since locally simply connected implies locally path connected, the above example implies we ought to add locally path connected to the list of hypotheses.  This implies every open subspace has a universal cover, but I'm not sure whether this means the space is locally simply connected.

Comment: $CX$ is semilocally simply connected as you say, but it's not true that each one of its open subset is semilocally simply connected ($X\times [0, 1)$ for example is not semilocally simply connected), so $CX$ is not a valid counterexample.

Comment: @mfox I misunderstood your question because of the re-use of the letter $U$ (I should have read it more carefully!)  I've replaced the answer, though I'd much rather have a counterexample that doesn't feel like it's getting by on a technicality.